# Compute $ \mathbb{P}\left(X_{1}+\cdots+X_{n}=0\right) $

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Assume $ \left(X_{n}\right)_{n} $ are independent random variables such that $ \mathbb{P}\left(X_{n}=1\right)=\frac{1}{2},\ldots,\mathbb{P}\left(X_{n}=-1\right)=\frac{1}{2}$. Define $S_{n}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}X_{n} $.

I have to compute the probability $ \mathbb{P}\left(S_{n}=0\right) $ .

I thought that it would just be $0 $ for an odd $ n $ and  $ 1/2^n $ for even $ n $ because there's exactly $2^n$ ways to choose the random variables that would equal $ -1 $, but I'm not sure this is correct.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe there is a typo in both the title and the description. Do you mean $\mathbb{P}(X_1+\dots + X_n = 0)$ and $\mathbb{P}(S_n = 0)$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**

Let $X_i = 2Y_i-1\:\forall\:1\le i\le n$. Then $Y_i$ are iid Bern$(\frac12)$ random variables. Now write $S_n$ in terms of $Y_i's$ and note that some of $n$ iid $Bern(p)$ random variables is $Bin(n,p)$.

**Full soln:**

Required probability reduces to:
\begin{align}
&P\left(\sum_{i=1}^nX_i=0\right)\\
=&P\left(2\sum_{i=1}^nY_i-n=0\right)\\
=&P\left(\sum_{i=1}^nY_i=\dfrac n2\right)\\
&=\begin{cases}
0&\text{if $n$ is odd}\\
\dbinom{n}{n/2}\dfrac{1}{2^n}&\text{if $n$ is even}
\end{cases}
\end{align}

Comment: Can you tell why the solution I suggested is not correct?

Comment: @FreeZe, because there are $\dbinom{n}{n/2}$ to choose positive random variables, not $2^n$. So required probability is the total number of choices multiplied by $\dfrac1{2^n}$.

Comment: I've also added the complete solution for your help now.